# What does "transfer start" mean in Postman?

Tags: api, postman, rest

I'm trying to figure out why it's taking long for an API to process my request and came upon this in Postman:

[image]

What does transfer start mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

https://community.postman.com/t/how-to-interpret-time-details-in-response-tab/5803

It has the same meaning has the dev tool response time.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference?utm_source=devtools#timing-explanation

so start time is the time required to get the first byte of the response and download time is the time taken to fetch the full data.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for how to find more info within the Transfer Start section. What I have tried so far is log the API functions related to the call. But even taking the microsecond timestamps of my functions on first and last it still leaves quite a lot of time that is unknown. Potentially this could be related to non code issues such as internet speed or server configuration. I would also recommend looking at caching or setting up cron jobs to clean up parts of the call that don't need to be there. In any case I also am looking to have more visibility on the Transfer Start part.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29846136)