# Postman response time "Transfer Start": Server responded right away but take a long time for response to round trip back?

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman

How do I interpret Postman response time ["Transfer Start"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66328322/what-does-transfer-start-mean-in-postman)? Apparently it's the time when the first byte of response is received.

[image]

I monitored the server log. Seems as soon as I fire off the request from Postman, the server responded. Does it mean I can conclude the slowness is coming from:

**Possibility 1:** Server slow to response to "Hello" call. (But by watching the log I think I can safely say it isn't the cause)

**Possibility 2:** Server responded right away, but that small response took a long time to round trip back (AWS transfer speed is asymmetric I think I remember outbound traffic is slow even Postman/My laptop and the VM resides in same region?)

Thanks